# See full msg debug with Node-RED

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, node-red

I'm running an application on Bluemix using Node-RED. I added a debug node to output the complete msg object, but it is being truncated in the debug console. How can I see the complete object?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can have the output sent to the console as well as the debug tab by checking a box in the debug node's config. The whole object will be sent to the console

The current debug tab will always truncate, but there are some plans to possibly add a separate debug window that could show the whole message. Also have a look in settings.js as I believe the character limit for when to truncate is set there, so if it's just too short you can increase it a bit.

EDIT:

I'd missed the bluemix tag earlier. To view the console log you need to use the cf command to tail the output. e.g. for a app called *node-red* you would run the following:

```
cf logs node-red
```

Comment: There are flows you can import for better debugging: http://flows.nodered.org/flow/b0fcb7b72fc05a30e55b

Comment: Where does console output get sent to? I only see debug/info views on the Node-RED page.

Comment: To the shell/console where you started node-red. This being bluemix it will end up in your apps log file. You can see this by running cf logs [app name]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can access your settings.js file but if you do, look for the debugMaxLength property and set it to a larger number. It will display more of your debug info.

Answer (score 0):

This also applies for the Node-RED add-on for Home Assistant. After changing the debugMaxLength value in config/node-red/settings.js, one needs to restart the add-on.